# Is is possible to create restful endpoint naming structure?

Tags: apex, rest-api, controller, rest

For instance, let's say you want to serve up contact 1111111's data.

I know you can make an endpoint like /contacts?id=1111111

Is it possible to have an endpoint like /contacts/1111111 where the apex code is able to get the value 1111111 instead of using a query parameter like the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can parse `RestContext.request.requestURI` to get that sort of information.

```
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/contacts/*')
global with sharing class MyRestService
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost()
    {
        List<String> path = RestContext.request.requestURI.split('/');
        // check for specific elements in the path
    }
}
```